# Should questions on meditation be on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am wondering if [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/1639/82) is on topic or not?

If so, would zazen questions be acceptable even if they have only a tenuous link to martial arts?

Where do we draw the line?

Comment: I wonder if someone is discussing transfer of meditating state to martial art training would be of topic.

Answer (score 5):

I am generally okay with that question on the site. It is somewhat tenuous to martial arts as you say, but I can see how meditation can be part of one's training.

From my (limited) perspective on martial arts, breathing is especially important in performing techniques. What you are describing I have also done in tai chi. I probably could answer it, but it's not easy. It took me a long time to even just get a basic grasp of what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree; I don't think the question is better answered by an expert martial artist than by an expert in any other field.  I believe the question is off-topic.

Comment: What do you agree with? Yes it is on topic, or no it isn't? :-)